# Is it better to check if element exists in a JS array, or add it and then run _.uniq?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Say you have an array of unique values and want to push new elements from another array, that meet a condition, without creating duplicates. E.g.

```
newArray.forEach(function(element){
  if (condition) {
    oldArray.push(element);
  }
})
```

With regards to performance in Javascript, is it better to check, in every iteration of the loop, if the element exists already before pushing to the array, or to add all the elements that meet the condition, and then run _.uniq from underscore.js?

```
newArray.forEach(function(element){
  if (condition && !oldArray.includes(element)) {
    oldArray.push(element);
  }
})
```

versus:

```
newArray.forEach(function(element){
  if (condition) {
    oldArray.push(element);
  }
})
oldArray = _.uniq(oldArray);
```

Maybe it doesn't really make a difference for small projects (and arrays), but I want to know what's best for a large scale project.

Comment: You may convert your array to a `Set` object and perform your additions safely like `mySet.add("whetever")`. The `Set` object should satisfy many of your needs however if you ever need reducing or mapping you may refer it like `[...mySet].reduce((p,c) => ..)`.

Comment: Thanks @Redu I will have a look at sets.

Answer (score 1):

```
_.uniq(oldArray);
```

will do an other loop of the array, so assuming the arrays are made of thousands elements surely the first solution is better.

Probably more usefull is to use `indexOf` instead of `includes`, infact, inside the includes funcion an `indexOf` is made:

```
newArray.forEach(function(element){
  if (condition && oldArray.indexOf(element)===-1) {
    oldArray.push(element);
  }
})
```

How you can see, the includes prototipe is:

```
String.prototype.includes = function(search, start) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof start !== 'number') {
      start = 0;
    }

    if (start + search.length > this.length) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1;
    }
  };
```

Comment: That's a valid point Mr.Bruno, but how about any optimizations run by underscore.js?

Comment: @tany4 thats true, but if you do the for and the uniq you will always make more loops instead using only the first for

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution would be to not use an Array but an object. Use key and value the same or your value as key and "true" as value:

```
{
  "value":"value"
}
```

or

```
{
  "value": true
}
```

while you're working with it. When you need the array of keys, convert with "for (p in obj)" to an array.

That way, operations in the array are unique by default without additional effort and only returning the array uses some calculations.

If your're using underscore or lodash, you can use _.keys(obj) as well.

Comment: OP didn't say that their values have keys to identify them.

Comment: thats why I suggested to use the value as key. Ah. Dammit.

Comment: Corrected my answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ok, but this still assumes they are strings (or can be reliably represented as strings).

Comment: Good Point. One can use an identifier from the element (id or similar) as Key and the Object as value and use _.values(obj) as well. ;)